how to convert json object to required format in react native javascript
I want to mould a JSON object into the following required format:
Here is the,
Input data:
  let data = {
      phone_number: phone.phoneInputValue,
      platform: 'app',
      device_id: uniqueId,
      device_type: 'app',
      channel: 'sms',
    };

and this I want to generate as Output:
{\"phone_number\"=>\"+916XXXXX998\",
     \"platform\"=>\"app\", \"device_id\"=>\"123456\", \"device_type\"=>\"abcde\",
     \"channel\"=>\"sms\"}

Achieved (the order is different) same I want to do for object keys currently its working on values only:
"channel=>\"sms\",device_id=>\"a6335b3b84eaf86b\",device_type=>\"app\",phone_number=>\"+916XXXXX998\",platform=>\"app\"

Method used:
 const formattedString = JSON.stringify(data)
      .replace(/\"([^"]+)\":/g, '$1=>')
      .replace(/[{}]/g, '');

Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks



let output = '{';
for (let key in data) {
    output += `\"${key}\"=>\"${data[key]}\", `;
}
output = output.slice(0, -2); 
output += '}';



Hope this helps and from the next time please make sure to not leak your phone number
